# Show that if $h \in C^1([a,b]\times[-ε,ε])$ with $ε>0$, then the function $s \in [-ε,ε] \mapsto \int_a^b h(t,s) \,dt$ is $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, fourier-analysis

Show that if $h \in C^1([a,b]\times[-ε,ε])$ with $ε>0$, then the function $$s \in [-ε,ε] \mapsto \int_a^b h(t,s) \,dt$$ is $C^1$ and $${d\over ds}\int_a^b h(t,s) \,dt=\int_a^b {\partial h \over \partial s}(t,s)\,ds$$

Any ideas how to show these parts?any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The partial derivative of $h$ is continuous in a compact set, thus is bounded, then one can use the bounded convergence theorem to move the limit inside the integral

Comment: Do you mean $\partial h / \partial s$ (`\partial h / \partial s`)? Anyway, the classical proof is dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, replace derivatives with integrals instead. For example,
\begin{align}
  \int_{-\epsilon}^{u}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}h(t,s)dtds
      & = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{-\epsilon}^{u}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}h(t,s)dsdt \\
      & = \int_{a}^{b}h(t,u)-h(t,-\epsilon)dt \\
      & = \int_{a}^{b}h(t,u)dt - C
\end{align}
The left side is differentiable in $u$, which means that the right side must also be. And, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
          \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial u}h(t,u)dt = \frac{d}{du}\int_{a}^{b}h(t,u)du.
$$
You do have to argue that $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}h(t,s)dt$ is a continuous function of $s$ in order to apply the Fundamental Theorem, and you have to argue that the interchange of orders of integration is justified by the joint continuity in $t$, $u$ of the integrand, but that's not so tough. In general, it's simpler to try to turn differentiation problems into integration and to interchange orders of integration than to try interchanging differentiation and integration.

Comment: How i can shiw the first part that is $C^1$?

Comment: @ParisD.R.Y. : The first equation I have in this post does that. The expression on the far right is $H(u)=\int_{a}^{b}h(t,u)dt$, which is seen to equal $C+\int_{-\epsilon}^{u}\left[\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}h(t,s)dt\right]ds$. The expression on the right in square brackets is a continuous function of $s$ and $H$ is the integral of that continuous function, making it continuously differentiable.

Comment: thanks.another question:for the second i have to show that  the interchange of orders of integration is justified by the joint continuity in t, u of the integrand?

Comment: @ParisD.R.Y. : Yes, ordinary rules of Riemann integration will do this for you. It's nice how basic these types of arguments can be kept.